# Variable number of columns in an HTML table

Tags: html, html-table

[image: example]

The highlighted area is two columns that I would like to collapse into one.

```html
<TABLE border="1" cellspacing="0" width="450px" cellpadding="3px" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
        <TR>
                <TD rowspan="2" width="50px" height="50px" background="img/noimg75.png"></TD>
                <TD width="200px">1</TD>
                <TD width="200px">2</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
                <TD>3</TD>
                <TD>4</TD>
        </TR>
        <TR>
                <TD>5</TD>
                <TD>6</TD>
                <TD>7</TD>
        </TR>
</TABLE>
```

Comment: Is the highlighted area the blue area with a `?` mark?  Or is it the yellow-outlined boxes? :)

Comment: Use a colspan? You seem to have found rowspan with no problem.

Comment: Also table:border, table:cellspacing, table:width, table:cellpadding, table:bordercolor, td:width, td:height, and td:background are all deprecated attributes in HTML 4.01 and unsupported in HTML 5. You should consider some CSS.

Comment: Thanks for the depreciation tip. I've just moved everything into CSS.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What's wrong with `colspan`?

```
<TABLE border="1" cellspacing="0" width="450px" cellpadding="3px" bordercolor="#FFFFFF">
    <TR>
        <TD rowspan="2" width="50px" height="50px" style="background:red;"></TD>
        <TD width="200px">1</TD>
        <TD width="200px">2</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD>3</TD>
        <TD>4</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan="2">5 & 6</TD>
        <TD>7</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```

?

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9XU9x/

UPDATE per comments:

```
<TD colspan="2"><table border="2" width="100%"><tr><td width="50%">Five</td><td>Six</td></tr></table></TD>
```

New demo: http://jsfiddle.net/TzXaF/

Comment: Hmm. I had tried that, but I must have had done something wrong. Sorry for the stupid question...

Comment: Follow up question: Now that the column is spanned across two columns, is there an easy way to split that new column into two equal parts?

Comment: Sure.  Many ways.  I've updated my answer with an ugly one (since you're already using tables).

Answer (score 1):

Using `colspan=""` would let you combine multiple `<td>`s.  Here is an example:

```
<TABLE>
    <TR>
        <TD>1</TD>
        <TD>2</TD>
    </TR>
    <TR>
        <TD colspan="2">3</TD>
    </TR>
</TABLE>
```